# How we can clear the cookie for Internet Explorer for Selenium automation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, qaf

We are currently automating using IE browser using Selenium webdriver. in order to run our test cases we need to clear the cookie from Registry and run test case to start from page 1. Can you help me out to  how we can do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _...clear the cookie from Registry..._?

Answer (score 0):

I hope question is not related to registry. There are two ways which doesn't need to work with registry key to clear cookies are:

1. set capability `ie.ensureCleanSession` to `true`

```
iexplorer.additional.capabilities={'ie.ensureCleanSession':true}
```

2. Through code delete all coockies

```
 driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Right place to put #2 is in [driver listener](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html#webdriver-listener) `onInitialize` method.

```
public void onInitialize(QAFExtendedWebDriver driver){
 driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
}
```